# Angular.js deep watch Coffeescript class instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript class like this:

```
class Foo
    constructor: (@bar) ->
        setTimeout () =>
            @bar = "changed!"
        , 5000)
```

And a list like this in my controller:

```
$scope.list = [new Foo("1"), new Foo("2")]
```

I have HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="baz in list">
        {{baz.bar}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

After 5 seconds, the values of the items in `$scope.list` change, but this is not reflected in the HTML.

Things are partially connected properly because if I add this code, everything works fine (albeit on a slight delay). The HTML is redrawn and updated properly.

```
setInterval () ->
    $scope.$apply () ->
        $scope.crashes = $scope.crashes
, 5000)
```

Is there any way to make sure the HTML updates when the properties on CoffeeScript class changes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
$scope.$watch('crashes', function (newVal) {
  $scope.crashes = newVal
}, true);
```

Setting the last param of $watch to true makes it a deep watch.

Comment: No that doesn't work. If place a breakpoint/`console.log` inside the callback, it isn't called when the properties inside the class are changed.

Comment: Actually, after a few minutes, it appears--but not immediately. Perhaps something else is causing the issue.

Comment: After 1 minute, I make a `$http` request in another controller. As soon as that `$http` request finishes an item in a different scope is updated. Around that time, the `$watch` callback is called.

Comment: Here's an explanation to why your callback is called only when the $http request finishes  - http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setTimeout since angularJS won't track changes and you will need to call $scope.$apply as you did. Use [$timeout](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq).

Edit: You can improve the custom timeout solution you posted by using $timeout and delete both the setInterval and the apply.

Comment: what do you do if you want to keep your classes angularjs free?

Comment: The `setTimeout` is the problem. It is actually an integration with a 3rd party library that takes a callback. I used `setTimeout` for a concise example of the problem.

Comment: @bekite the $timeout is necessary even if you are watching the model. If you want to keep your classes angularjs free then use setTimeout but take a callback that will use $apply

Comment: @AlecGorge since it's a third-party you don't want to change it seems like you are stuck with your timeout solution. You can improve it by using $timeout and delete both the setInterval and the apply.